# Whitelist email sent by Wordpress

Tags: email, wp-mail

What need users to put in the whitelist of their mailbox to prevent WP generated mails to end up in spam?

Say the server use something like that:

```
wp_mail( 'someone@example.net', 'The subject', 'The message', 'From: My Name <myname@example.com>' );
```

Is it working if users just put 'myname@example.com' in the whitelist? Or what should they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly, this also has nothing to do with WordPress. It is more web server whitelisting issue. You should start with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629614/whitelisting-website-email-so-it-is-not-rejected-as-spam).

SPF records are important.

And maybe your web server has IP address that is blacklisted. You may even consider different IP address from your provider.